# Why Vue SFC can be used as parameters of InstanceType

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3

this is my test code:

```js
import type HelloWorld from './helloWorld.vue'
type HelloWorldInstance = InstanceType<typeof HelloWorld>
```

the typescript of the source code of InstanceType:

```js
type InstanceType<T extends abstract new (...args: any) => any> = T extends abstract new (...args: any) => infer R ? R : any;
```

indicates that it receives a generic parameter type T, which is limited to the abstract class constructor type.

But the `HelloWorld` I print out is an object

[image]

so, Why Vue SFC can be used as parameters of InstanceType?

Comment: You could start with checking what `typeof HelloWorld` is in your case, it doesn't really matter what it is at runtime. Currently this depends on your case because .vue files are non-spec, the way they are handled depends on your setup and IDE. It's unknown how you observe this behaviour, it could pass in IDE but fail on build, and vice versa. Generally, yes, InstanceType should error when provided with plain object and not a constructor. This is probably XY problem because you need ComponentPublicInstance